# Albert hotkey issues

Tags: albert

On Ubuntu 20.04 the key binding Super+X doesn't work. The key sometimes does work sometimes not. What is the problem and what should I do to get my hotkey set up properly?

Comment: General note: I am an established user here and I pay attention to tags, but I remember as a new user I did not. If not noticing the `albert` tag may make readers interpret the question as broader than you intended, then it's good to add "I'm using Albert" in the body. Tags in titles are sometimes frowned upon, but clear information in the body is OK. The point is some newcomer may find this question when struggling with registering keys in an *unrelated* program, seeking *generic* answer. Your answer gives some generic insight, but the last part may make them think Albert can help *them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the window system refuses to register the key combination this may have many causes.

The most prominent is that *another application already grabbed the key* combo. If you really want to get exactly that combo, your best bet is to find out which application grabbed the key and disable the grab. In virtually every case this will be your desktop environment, respectively its window manager, e.g. Compiz (Unity), KWin (KDE), Mutter (Gnome), or Muffin (Cinnamon). If it is possible remove the desired key combination from the system's keyboard settings and try again to set it Albert. If the grab is hardcoded you're out of luck.

If you happen to be running Wayland, it gets even weirder. *Wayland does not allow to grab keys* at all (2018). Magically the hotkey works on X11 windows running inside your Wayland DE, but not on Wayland windows. Out of luck again. We (standalone app devs) still wait for a standardized way to register hotkeys.

Also sometimes *crappy window managers globally intercept the keypress events of modifiers*. E.g. Unity (Ubuntu) grabs <kbd>Meta</kbd>. Therefore you can not use any combination of <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>. The event is simply not delivered.

Fortunately there is a suboptimal but **general workaround**: Let your desktop environment handle the registration of hotkeys and run the command `albert show` or `albert toggle` on activation. This method implies that a process has to be run and is somewhat heavy therefore.